# Titan IdGraph get Edge by Id slow

Tags: titan, rexster

I setup a Titan 0.5.2 Graph with DynamoDB as the backend. And I configured the Graph to be wrapped in an IdGraph. When I try to get an edge using our custom id from the IdGraph it takes about a minute, but when I try to get the edge using the default id from the regular Graph it takes less than a second.

```
graph.getEdge("id") // less than second
idGraph.getEdge("customId") // over a minute
```

What could be leading to this difference?

Comment: I'm guessing customId is an edge property? did you set an index on this and if so can you show us how?

Comment: The index was created when I configured it to be an IdGraph, as shown here, https://github.com/tinkerpop/rexster/wiki/Specific-Graph-Configurations

Comment: This issue almost always points to indexing problems.  How long does it take to look up that edge using your index directly via `graph.E('customId',"id")`? does that also take over a minute?

Comment: yes, that also takes over a minute

Comment: How big is your graph (edges/vertices)?  Can you also please update your question to include your index creation code?